# RXJS Create Observable for sockets

Tags: sockets, rxjs, reactive-programming, pusher

I'm trying to return an Observable from a service that would allow you to listen to any Pusher channel.

Works fine, expect I'd like to `unsubscribe` from the pusher channel when the Observable (generated using `createRealtimeObservable(...)`) was unsubscribed from.

Any ideas?

```
  public realtimeObservable (channelName, eventName): Observable<any> {

        const realtimeObservable$ = new Observable((observer) => {

          const channel = this.pusher.subscribe(`private-organization-${this.authService.userProfile.organization_id}-${channelName}`)
          channel.bind(eventName, (data) => {
            observer.next(data.payload)
          })

        })

        return realtimeObservable$
      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you manually create an Observable yourself it is your responsibility to cleanup all resources when unsubscribed to. Luckily the Observable has a mechanism for this by allowing you to return an unsubscribe/dispose function when creating:

```
return Observable.create((obs) => {
  const channel = this.pusher.subscribe(`private-organization-${this.authService.userProfile.organization_id}-${channelName}`)
  channel.bind(eventName, (data) => {
    observer.next(data.payload)
  });

  return () => {
    // unsubscribe event
    channel.unsubscribe(); // NOTE: i do not know the syntax for unsubscribing a Pusher channel, impl as required.
  };
});
```

NB: [`Observable.create()`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/Observable#create) is syntactic sugar for `new Observable()`